# How to install the exe correctly using chocolatey?

Tags: windows, chocolatey

[image]

this is my nuget

```
$packageName = 'filezillaInstall'
$version = '3.14.0'
$fileType = 'exe'
$silentArgs = '/S'
$url = "D:\Exe\filezillaInstall'
$url64bit = "D:\Exe\filezillaInstall'
$validExitCodes = @(0, 1223)

Install-ChocolateyPackage $packageName $fileType $silentArgs $url $url64bit -validExitCodes $validExitCodes
```

Comment: You should ask the question in a plain text and paste the actual code into the question, not posting the image which is discouraged. See: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/55075).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url locations should be able to be accessed from anywhere. If you point it to a local directory, it will only work where that local directory also contains that file. Don't go by the local temporary location that choco uses to download the installer, you should move it somewhere else like a CIFS/SMB share that every computer on your network can access, or if the installer is small enough (less than 50MB), embed it into the package.

Comment: i done that for just testing purpose. the exe located it a public drive on the network. i want to know whether my pointing is correct or wrong. and after i download the nuget from repo, it downloading to my download folder, so im pointing to that location and executing that nuget(inside nuget it pointed to the exe location). is this steps are wrong? because it giving me errors. and how to excute that downloaded nuget correctly from command prompt. it prompting "........ it is possible that the package name exists but the version does not.
 Version: "" "

Comment: Don't use name.nupkg, just name. When you are calling choco install that is

Comment: Once you edit the pkg, you do need to call choco pack to get a nupkg with a version.